# String constructor has not been recognized in switch/case

Tags: node.js, typescript

In below code sample, the value of `targetValueSpecification.type` is `String` as `sampleType`:

```js
const sampleType = String;

console.log("Sample type:");
console.log(sampleType);
switch (sampleType) {

  case String: {
    console.log("String");
    break;
  }
  default : {
    console.log("Not string?")
  }
}

console.log();
console.log("Some external data:");
console.log(targetValueSpecification.type);
switch (targetValueSpecification.type) {
  case String: {
    console.log("String");
    break;
  }
  default : {
    console.log("Not string?")
  }
}
```

The output was unexpected for me:

[image]

This code in being executed on the server side of NuxtJS application (it means NodeJS), but locally.

The value of `targetValueSpecification.type` refers to:

```
namespace User {

  export namespace ID {
    export const type: StringConstructor = String; // Here
  }
  // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this in TypeScript Playground ([attempt](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVKEBOSDeBYAUAUkhAB4wD2GALkqJLAsgJIAiORxJ5Vt8FwKLWoBPGBABcSAMrUMAS2ABzAMIChGAK7xqVJAF4ZcxUoDcSAPQWkACUwROAX05WkAOg8FnhfP0G0ocBgAGwgAFTFJIwVlNX8tHT1DWRizAgIoAHd5angACyQACkCwEPDIgEoOfC4keBB0aJMpPBrarj8oClC3YIolQoAiFJNBitNOdqQAIwwIEABrCbbib1qAEwgAMxBNYNoWyfbO7ohe-qGAOQoA42UAfjGj728M7NyCwrRMNzY3UXEVVatXqjRGykOK2O6lO5wGwzuSjGyymxFm8yWzyOmx2ewO1VRdRhPT68Out1SjwqWPwr3wQA)). So, the variables in this equation are including:

1. TypeScript - the source code
2. NodeJS
3. NuxtJS

I am very interesting what this phenomenon is.

Comment: We really can't help you without a [mcve] here. If you can't reproduce this yourself, how could we? The code you've shown works. There are no leads that hint at anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ry- suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848689/isstring-number-objectconstructor-check-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment123470098_69848689) on the other question

> Nuxt.js could be bringing in a `String` constructor from a [different
> execution environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_e.g._frames_or_windows)
> somehow.

While that sounds unlikely to me, it's certainly possible, next to everything else that displays as `[Function: String]` in the console. (`function String() {}` would, for example).

While you definitely need to investigate where this function comes from and what it actually is, here are two workarounds that should quickfix this:

- switch on `typeof sampleType()`. If they're the builtin constructors, they will return `0`, `""` and `{}` respectively, which have the types `"number"`, `"string"` and `"object"`.
- switch on `sampleType.name`. If they're the builtin constructors, their names will be `"Number"`, `"String"` and `"Object"` respectively.

Comment: The second solution was ideal for my case. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

String refers to the String constructor in your top most assignment (which is a function)

In other words you actually just got a reference to the string constructor function assigned to sampleType

You should be using typeof instead of String.type to get a string of the type which for String is function and not "String".

typeof String = 'Function'

typeof "String" = 'String'

Your switch on SampleType is comparing the reference of the String function to the String function which is true.

String.type is undefined as far as I'm aware which is why you hit the default in the second switch

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but looks like I confused you with `.type.` `targetValueSpecification.type` refers to `User.ID.type`. Did you mean that `export const type: StringConstructor = String;` must be the `"string"`?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something that would be export type User ={ID:{type:string}} ?

Comment: In the real project, there is the `type User ={ID:{type:string}}` (merged with `User ` namespace). But the `User` is being retrieved from the external data source like data base or HTTP, so initially it has `any` type. Before cast it to `User`, it's required to validate it, therefore define the validation rules somewhere. This is what namespace `User` exists for.