# isString/Number/ObjectConstructor check in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

As I knew experimentally, the detecting of the constructor type via `switch/case` basically works, but sometimes could [bring the surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69848208/4818123).

```
const TYPE: NumberConstructor | StringConstructor | ObjectConstructor = String;

switch(TYPE) {
  case Number: {
    // any applied code
  }
  case String: {
    // any applied code
  }
  case Boolean: {
    // any applied code
  }
}
```

But how to explore which constructor is `TYPE`?
`StringConstructor`, `NumberConstructor` are interfaces and there is no type guards for them.

Please don't touch the `TYPE` during this topics.

Comment: What do you mean by "*how to explore which constructor is `TYPE`?*", doesn't your `switch` distinguish them as expected? What is the code in `...`? Are you getting an error?

Comment: [worksforme](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgTQAoFEYF4YGUoCcCWYA5jAIYQwByArgLYBGAprgMLjS7XBQi4wA+2PISJtIeLjz6CA8vQBWjbmI6TeAbgBQmiAHd8UYAAsAFIlQBKGAG9NMGMHKMqdJrgBcNu-YftYYDHhkFBMAcgBGUIstHxh6XEZSAGsYmABfb0cIZxwCYk9bWNBxGApMcxCAFgAmaO97eMSU7wz7LOc5RW4C+t8SkECKkzrYxuTUjLSgA)

Comment: @Bergi " What do you mean..." - Yes. "doesn't your switch distinguish them as expected" - Basically yes, but [sometimes it does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69848208/4818123). "What is the code in ..." - any constructor type dependent applied code; it does not matter for this topics.

Comment: "*but sometimes it does not work*" - dunno, that seems to be [a separate topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69848208/4818123). What does not work here, what is the question here?

Comment: @Bergi "what is the question here" - how to check is value the `StringConstructor` (or `NumberConstructor`, `ObjectConstructor`, etc.). I suppose the switch/case works not always.

Comment: But it does. Your supposition is wrong. There is no problem here.

Comment: Nuxt.js could be bringing in a `String` constructor from a [different execution environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_e.g._frames_or_windows) somehow. The way to address that problem, if it is the problem and it can’t be changed, depends on what you’re trying to accomplish by comparing these types with each other.

Comment: @Ry-, thank you for the comment. "Nuxt.js could be bringing in a String constructor from a different execution environment " - looks like this is the cause.  "depends on what you’re trying to accomplish by comparing these types with each other." - the validation. In the real project the `TYPE`  is going from the validation rules and the comparing (switch/case) is being executed inside the validator.

Comment: @Ry- This might be possible but seems unlikely. Where would nuxtjs (running in node) get a different environment from? Either way, please post that as answer on the other question, let's close this one.

Comment: @Bergi, fine, but before close this question I want to make the verdict. Do you declare that basically the constructor exploring via switch/case is the working methodology?

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD It's a fine methodology and TypeScript does like it, yes - it normally works. If it doesn't work for you, we need more details on how that happens.

Comment: @Bergi, OK, I merged the comments to the answer. I can't close this question myself, but accept that it will be closed. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi said, normally the `switch`/`case` works fine.

But there could be come special cases like Universal mode in NuxtJS. According @-Ry-, NuxtJS could be bringing in a String constructor from a different execution environment somehow. However, the Stack Overflow rules requires this special case be considered on other question.